# Image goes outside ImageButton

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

[image]

Both ImageButtons and Image were added programmatically:

```
//some code...
int pixelsToDp = convertToPixelsDp(-4.5f);
params.setMargins(pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp);
//some code...
ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
                    btn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                    btn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    buttonRow.add(btn);
```

Image was added by setBackgroundResource() function. How to make image be fully inside the ImageButton? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I've got to ask why do you need the button and not just use the background but with image for the bomb, and maybe post more code, would be much easier to help out. But if you prefer we might just concentrate on the fitting of image in a button.

Comment: @kirotab I need the button, because the image appears when it is clicked. I do not think there may need any other code, because the posted one is the only one relating to the issue. I just need to fit it inside the ImageButton. Thank you.

Comment: @kirotab by the way, do you remember you have answered the question about how to remove spaced between elements of this matrix? :) You made that day of mine, thank you once more :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, programmers need to eat sometimes :). You're welcome for the other day, and for today we'll have to use a combination of my suggestions there, will come back with some code in a minute but you might have to do some changes maybe

Comment: What I proposed not working ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this class in a new file but for the test might be the same file

```
class MyImageButton extends ImageButton
{
    MyImageButton(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        Log.v("measure", "width:" + w + " height:" + h);
        if(w != h) {

            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    w, w
            );
            int pixelsToDp = convertToPixelsDp(-4.5f);
            params.setMargins(pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp);
            this.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
}
```

Now use your newly created class instead of the original `ImageButton`

```
ImageButton btn = new MyImageButton(this);
```

Also change this if you want your image to be scaled

```
btn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

(I've tested with `btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);` )

**Some explanation in case it works :)**

In our `ImageButton` extending class we're overriding `onSizeChanged` and there we're setting new layout parameters, they are not calculated by the `weight` anymore but are set to fixed values, but that's not a problem as the first time they were already calculated by the weight so it should work on different devices also.

Again we have to remove the margins, you could extract that part in some precalculated variables in order to not do this calculation for all items.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this.Is just to change picture size.I was doing so.

Comment: True but not a permanent fix I think, that way your size is no longer dynamically calculated (I mean it's taken from the image size)

Comment: @Void What size should I make it?

Comment: Sorry i was away from PC.Just try a few times to make it fit the space for it.There is no specific size.Just try to make it smaller while it wont be good.

Comment: http://photoshop.camtasia.com.ua/
изображение->изменить размер.(меняй 1 параметр второй автоматом подгонится)

Comment: And for each screen size you should provide different picture.